# ng-bootstrap Basic Usage example

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have installed `ng-bootstrap` in my project.

in `app.module.ts` I imported

```
 import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I also added the declaration

`imports:[ NgbModule.forRoot(),BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing]`

Might be a stupid question but what do I do now to get the bootstrap benefits?

Thanks

Comment: I pasted sample html into my app.component.html file which contains bootstrap class references but they dont seem to use the bootstrap library.

Comment: Did you look at the demo page and the associated examples? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion

Comment: I see those examples now and have some of them working nicely. Thanks for that. However, I thought I would also be able to use the bootstrap css classes for general html in my .html files.

Comment: as soon as you load Bootstrap's CSS you can use it anywhere - this has nothing to do with ng-bootstrap. ng-bootstrap is building _on top_ of Bootstrap's CSS but it doesn't prevent you from using Bootstrap CSS anywhere you want.